# Problem with class change in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I need to change the class of an element on mouseover event and it doesn't fire. But if I add an alert in the function it does work.

Doesn't work:

```
mouseenter: function(){
    $('#id-b-red').addClass('mouseover')
}
```

Does work:

```
mouseenter: function(){
   alert('$%!# IE')
   $('#id-b-red').addClass('mouseover')
}
```

Maybe this has something to do with me using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements?

```
.mouseover:before,
.mouseover .btn-before,
.mouseover:after,
.mouseover .btn-after{
    background-position: 0 -33px;
}
```

but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @MattBall ha - i was making the same edit :-P

Comment: you should include ";" at the end of statements

Comment: @ALL: Sorry. Was working on the translation ;)

Comment: @Joseph, and u changed the OP's code, don't do that.... (i changed it back)

Comment: @UkuLoskit -- you should, but you don't need to

Comment: @Neal: I honestly have no idea how that happened...

Comment: @OP: what does alert($('#id-b-red').length); say?

Comment: @Neal: Actually, I do know how it happened. While I was editing his code, he changed it, so that when I saved, it overwrote what he had changed (as well as Matt Ball's change). Why doesn't SO inform you when a change has been made, the same way it alerts you of additional answers while you're writing yours?

Comment: well, then the event fires and the element is matched. probably the class is also applied, but your css selectors are wrong. look at element with firebug after the mouseover addClass. And please use $('#id-b-red').addClass('mouseover'); (with semicolon). Add a CSS rule: .mouseover { background-color: red }

Comment: also after addClass do: alert($("#id-b-red").hasClass("mouseover").toString());

Comment: with class .mouseover { background-color: red } it works without alert. alert($("#id-b-red").hasClass("mouseover").toString()); says 'true' and $("#id-b-red") changes, but it doesn't change without alert

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as has been stated in the comments, Javascript code requires semi-colons to end each statement. You can *get away* without them in *some* cases (where you only have one line in a block), which is why the original code worked without the `alert`, but I suspect this may be why adding the `alert` is not working. Good Javascript code should have a semicolon on the end of every line.

Secondly: please state what version of IE you're testing with (and what versions you need to work with). You're using `:before` and `:after`. Please note that these pseudo-selectors only work in IE8 and above. They do not work in IE6 or IE7. Therefore, if you're testing with an older version of IE (or in a newer version, but with quirks mode or compatibility mode in use), then `:before` and `:after` will be broken.

Comment: @Neal - wow, that article is a massive rant. And wrong. It is right that they're optional *in some cases*, but wrong that they're useless. (He's also wrong about curly braces). He's arguing against recognised good practice. He even includes a caveat where his own arguments completely fall apart and demonstrate exactly why he's wrong. (then he argues for putting semicolons at the front of some lines. wow. just wow. I'm going to forget I ever read that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It works for me in all browsers...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#testBox').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).addClass('greenClass');
        });

        $('#testBox').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('greenClass');
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .redClass{
        background-color:red;
    }

    .greenClass{
        background-color:green;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="testBox" style="height:30px; width:30px;" class="redClass"></div>
</body>
```